# I want to change any + or - to "plus" and "minus" in a text file by cpp. I was able to print everything in the file but i couldn't change the chara

Tags: c++, file, search, replace, edit

```
   #include <fstream>
   #include <sstream>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string.h>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
 {
  ifstream inFile("registration.txt");
  ofstream outFile("replaced.txt");
 ifstream readFile("registration.txt");


vector<vector<string> > table;
if (inFile.is_open())
{
    string line;
    while( getline(inFile,line) )
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        vector<string> separated_fields;
        cout<<line<<endl;
        cout<<"----"<<endl;

        string ID, fname, lname;
        getline(ss,ID,',');
        separated_fields.push_back(ID);
        getline(ss,fname,',');
                    separated_fields.push_back(fname);

        getline(ss,lname,',');
        separated_fields.push_back(lname);

        //vector<string> enrolled;
        string course;
        while( getline(ss,course,',') )

        {
              //  cout<<"loop"<<endl;
             separated_fields.push_back(course);
        }
        cout<<separated_fields[0];
        cout<<"\n";

    table.push_back(separated_fields);
    }
}
cout<<"------------------"<<endl;
```

// cout<<table.size();
//cout<<table[0].size()<<endl;

```
  for(int i=0 ;i<table.size();i++){
  for(int j=0 ;j<table[0].size();j++){

  cout<<table[i][j]<<"\t\t";
  }
     cout<<endl;

  }
```

[image]
return 0;
}
I was able to print everything in the file but i couldn't change the character. i tried to do search and replace but u couldn't too. there is a vector of vectors called table that contain all the lines of the file.

Comment: Is there anything in this code that attempts to change those characters? What should they be changed _to_?

Comment: into words. + to "plus", - to "minus"

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated function in C++ to replace something in a string by something else. It is called: `std::regex_replace`. The description can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace)

See some example code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    const std::string test = "a + b   a+b  +++ + + +plus+";

    std::cout << std::regex_replace(test, std::regex(R"(\+)"), "plus");

    return 0;
}
```

But, from your description, I do not exactly know . . .